# Ошибка в XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть текстбокс, ставлю на backgroung фотку. Код:

```
<TextBox.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="moleskine.png"/> //тут на / указывает
</TextBox.Background>
```

Вроде все правильно. Поискал в интернете, но там тоже точно такой же код! 
Ошибка: подчеркивает красным `/>`

[image: В чем проблема-то?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно адресуете ресурс, надо

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/pic/Koala.jpg"></ImageBrush>
```

где:

- WpfApplication1 -- имя сборки
- pic/Koala.jpg -- путь к рисунку в
     проекте.

Это если вы используете рисунок как ресурс в проекте. Та запись, что вы использовали, может(?) сработать, разве что, для рисунка лежащего в корне проекта.